# Which Twilight 2000 rules system did GDW's Cadillacs and Dinosaurs game use?

Tags: cadillacs-and-dinosaurs

I believe there have been three versions of the [*Twilight 2000*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_2000) rules. There was the first edition. Then *Twilight 2000 version 2*. And then they updated this book to Version 2.2 to make it compatible with *[Traveller: The New Era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller%3a_The_New_Era#Traveller%3a_The_New_Era_.281993.2C_GDW.29)*. Which of these *Twilight 2000* rules did *[Cadillacs and Dinosaurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenozoic_Tales)* RPG use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T2K Edition 1 is a wholly unrelated game engine.

House System version 1: Note that the GDW House System begins not in T2K, but in Space 1889. It later gets revised into T2K; it used 1d6 vs Skill + modfiers, or (Skill)d6's totaled vs a TN ala Star Wars, or (skill)d6's individually vs a TN by difficulty counting successes.

House System version 2: T2K Edition 2, aka T2K 2.0 is the 1d10 version, and also was used in Dark Conspiracy 1E. 3 Difficulty levels: 1d10 vs Skill x2, x1, and x1/2, Roll Low

House System Version 3: T2K Edition 2.2 is the 1d20 version, used in DC edition 2. 5 Difficulty levels, 1d20 vs (Stat+Skill) x4, x2, x1, x1/2, x1/4, Roll Low. Character Gen is identical to 2.0 save for a couple of errata entries. Combat is revised slightly.

House System Version 4: The 4th version of the House Engine is Traveller: The New Era. It makes many additional changes to 2.2's engine, especially in Character Generation and Combat. Equipment is compatible, and characters close.

Sometimes reference is made to T2K 2.1; no such rulebook was printed, but the upgrades to tasks of 2.2 were previewed in the Ref's Screen for 2.0, and some refer to that rules upgrade as 2.1; 2.2 made additional changes above and beyond those.

All of the Dark Conspiracy and T2K 2E materials are compatible, even with the change of dice mechanics in T2K2.2 and DC2.

**Based upon the time released, and reviews online, I believe it's based upon T2K 2.0.**

It can easily be "upgraded" to 2.2; the differences are few.

I will note that I never bought it because the Character Generation method was different from the T2K2/DC Character Generation. But note also: I've read (repeatedly over the many years) that C&D has other mechanical differences besides CGen.